# Loading an image from plist

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

im working on a game where, every "stage" id like to load an image that comes from a plist. This is my plist [image]

```
  NSDictionary *config=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:
                                                                   @"Levels" ofType:@"plist"]];


  NSDictionary *PicData = config[@"levels"];
    NSString *images = [PicData objectForKey:@"playerIcon"];
```

However, I am getting an error on the last line when run. Not exactly sure why since I am saying spritenode With image named Images which you get from the dictionary.  Thank you, any help would be appreicated

Comment: You make no attempt to get the proper value from the dictionary. You need to dig into the "levels" array and then get the proper level dictionary. Then you can get the "playerIcon".

Comment: @rmaddy I have editted my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you don't know how to dig into the proper part of the plist file.

```
// Get the top-level dictionary
NSDictionary *config=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Levels" ofType:@"plist"]];
```

Now you need to get the "levels" array:

```
NSArray *levels = config[@"levels"];
```

Now you need to know which level you want. Once you know the level, you can get the dictionary for that level:

```
NSDictionary *levelData = levels[someLevelNumber];
```

Now you can get the player icon:

```
NSString *imageName = levleData[@"playerIcon"];
```

Comment: Thanks,, i see what I was missing

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get the icon for the first level:

```
NSString *images = PicData[@"levels"][0][@"playerIcon"];
```

I changed this from the top of my head, not sure if it will throw an error because each accessor returns an object of type 'id' by default. I also changed it to the new indexers which make code like this a lot more readable as you can imagine.